# How can I make my search more broad?

Tags: php, mysql

I created this search mysql string and it is to literal or maybe un-literal?
If I search for Dave for example it will only find items like "Dave something" and not find Dave.

```
$queryArtist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE artist LIKE '%$ArtistNameSearch%' ORDER BY artist ASC");
```

I know mysql_query is out dated and will change it to mysqli soon as I get this worked out. Stuck here.

An example of it no working is 
[Example of search](http://www.thelyricsfinder.com/searchlyrics.php?term=one%20direction)

Could it be becasue the %20 space?

I got it figured out, but it still does NOT find one direction or other things even those exist.
here is what I have now

```
$queryArtist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists WHERE match(artist) against('$SafeSearchTerm' in boolean mode)");
```

Comment: Your query looks alright for me. It should return `Dave` as a result.

Comment: You probably have trailing spaces? Try a `trim()` before passing it into the query.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to be using a [full-text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) rather than the `LIKE` statement to get more flexibility.

Comment: Your answer is more like a comment!

Comment: It's a solution, not a comment.

Comment: There is a link to adequate explanations. However, saying "full-text index" is often a much greater gift than copy, paste, job's a guddun. The user has something to search Google for and they can learn about it and actually understand what is going on. It gives them the ability to help themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use Soundex or sounds like. See this [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)